# Setting Table level permissions on Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have a requirement with a (supposedly) pre-existing item, where an Azure sync'd AD group "SQL Users" was granted read access to a database running in Azure.

Apparently, this group was assigned write permissions to specific tables in this database and it needs to be expanded to 3 more.

I'm fairly green to Azure, so I poked around and couldn't find any references to this group in the SQL instance at all, but did find it within the resource group with read permissions, but I can't seem to edit that at all.

Any ideas? I'm stuck.

Investigated SQL Instance for requested group
Checked Azure shell for role assignments, found it there but didn't tell me anything about the existing read access.

What I need to achieve:
Assign an Azure AD Group with existing read access, write access to specific tables in Azure SQL, preferably without things breaking :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign an Azure AD Group with existing read access, write access to specific tables in Azure SQL, you can follow the procedure below:

Set admin to Azure SQL database:

Log in with admin into the SQL database and create a user using the command below:

```
CREATE USER [ADadmin] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

Grant the required access using the command below:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON [Schema].[table] TO [ADadmin];
```

[image]

After granting the permissions, group members will access the table as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Bhavani, thanks for the reply! I've tried this as well, but errors out stating that only connections established with Active Directory accounts can create other Active Directory users, but I'm using a global/Azure admin account which is also a local domain admin account, so I'm quite lost.

I should also mention that the group in question is a security group with no email, I'm not sure if display name works as intended with that one.

Comment: Set your account as SQL database admin and login with that account once.

Comment: That ended up working but it was a bit more weird. The account that was listed as the owner, listed as the entra admin for the subscription as well, needed to be RE-ADDED as an owner to the resource, which makes no sense to me. After that I was able to add the group and get the permissions in SQL set, so thank you for the assistance!